# What does "a front for" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am an IELTS test-taker. I am fond of using procon.org as English study material. Anyway I have a question about a sentence on the website.

> Medical marijuana is **a front for** drug legalization and recreational use.

I do not fully understand this sentence. As I understood, it looks like "Medical marijuana is regarded as a first try to be drug legalization and tecreational ise".
Am I right? 
Thanks for replyers.

Comment: For an explanation of the expression, see: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/front+for

Answer (score 2):

if thing A is a "front for" thing B, then thing A is acting as a disguise for thing B. The author of the sentence is suggesting that people or organisations promoting medical marijuana are often  promoting the legalization and recreational use of marijuana.

> front
>   noun
>   (APPEARANCE)
>
> ​ 
>   the character or qualities that a person or
>   organization appears to have in public that are different from their
>   real character or qualities, and whose purpose is often to deceive
>   people or hide an illegal activity:
>
> Don't be fooled by his kindness and sensitivity - it's just a front.
>
> She presents such a cheerful front that you'd never guess she's ill.
>
> The machinery company was a front operation for arms smuggling.
>
> Several trading companies were set up in the early 1960s to act as
>   fronts for money-laundering operations.

[Front (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/front)